# Wagtail Internationalization, how to select language for a page?

Tags: internationalization, wagtail

I want to build a site in 'nl' and 'en', followed the docs:
https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/i18n.html#enabling-internationalisation

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
WAGTAIL_I18N_ENABLED = True
WAGTAIL_CONTENT_LANGUAGES = LANGUAGES = [
    ('nl', "Nederlands"),
    ('en', "English")
]
```

But I don't get an option to select the language when creating a page.
Not sure how it supposed to work. Should I use a Mixin?

Wagtail 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the 'en' locale in the Settings > Locales menu?

Not sure if this is wagtail core or a wagtail-localize feature ...

I'd recommend using [wagtail-localize](https://www.wagtail-localize.org/), it makes translation so much easier than anything else I've tried. There's an easy to follow tutorial on the doc site.

Current version (1.6) supports up to Wagtail 5.1.3, new version (1.7) due very soon.

Comment: Yes, I've added 'en' in de locales menu. It has 1 page in 'nl' an 0 in 'en'.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it by adding 'wagtail.contrib.simple_translation' to installed apps.
After I have created a 'nl' page I get a 'translate' option for that page.